# Al aplicar la funcion entry.get() de tkinter no retorna ningun valor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, get, ventana

Mi problema es que escribo datos en el campo entry y luego al aplicar la funcion get() esta me retorna vacio. Aca coloco una parte de mi codigo. En otra seccion de mi codigo declaro las variables de la misma manera y si hace la lectura de datos correctamente, el problema radica en esta ventana TopLevel().

def editarCliente(self):

```
    #ventana emergente para facilitar la edicion del cliente
    self.editarclienteWind = Toplevel()
    self.editarclienteWind.title('Modificar datos del cliente')

    #Frame para los datos
    self.frameEditarCliente = LabelFrame(self.editarclienteWind, text = 'Actualizacion de cliente')
    self.frameEditarCliente.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)

    # modificar cedula
    Label(self.frameEditarCliente, text = 'Nueva cedula:').grid(row = 1, column = 3)
    self.nuevoCedula = Entry(self.frameEditarCliente)
    self.nuevoCedula.focus()
    self.nuevoCedula.grid(row = 1 , column = 4)     
    #Modificar nombre
    Label(self.frameEditarCliente, text = 'Nuevo nombre:').grid(row = 2, column = 3)
    self.nuevoNombre = Entry(self.frameEditarCliente)
    self.nuevoNombre.grid(row = 2, column = 4)
    #Modificar Apellido
    Label(self.frameEditarCliente, text = 'Nuevo apellido:').grid(row = 3, column = 3)
    self.nuevoApellido = Entry(self.frameEditarCliente)
    self.nuevoApellido.grid(row = 3, column = 4)
    #Modificar Alias        
    Label(self.frameEditarCliente, text = 'Nuevo alias: ').grid(row = 4, column = 3)
    self.nuevoAlias = Entry(self.frameEditarCliente)
    self.nuevoAlias.grid(row = 4, column = 4)
    #Modificar Telefono
    Label(self.frameEditarCliente, text = 'Nuevo telefono').grid(row = 5, column = 3)
    self.nuevoTelefono = Entry(self.frameEditarCliente)
    self.nuevoTelefono.grid(row = 5, column = 4)
    #Modificar Direccion
    Label(self.frameEditarCliente, text = 'Nueva direccion').grid(row = 6, column = 3)
    self.nuevoDireccion = Entry(self.frameEditarCliente)
    self.nuevoDireccion.grid(row = 6, column = 4)


    print("revisar valores ")
    print(self.nuevoCedula.get())
    print(self.nuevoNombre.get())
    print(self.nuevoApellido.get())
    print(self.nuevoAlias.get())
    print(self.nuevoTelefono.get())
    print(self.nuevoDireccion.get())
    print("Fin de revisar valores")
```

Comment: ¿El código que imprime el valor de los Entrys en que momento se ejecuta? ¿Está asociado al click de un botón para poder leer lo que se encuentre ingresado en los Entrys?

Comment: Si, esos print los tengo a modo de prueba, en realidad con esos valores creo una tupla que luego paso a la funcion que ejecuta el query. Este seria el boton:
ttk.Button(self.editarclienteWind, text = 'Aceptar', command = lambda: self.updateCliente(parametros)).grid(row = 7, column = 4, sticky = W + E)

Comment: Prueba aplicar el método grid en una línea aparte. Hay inconvenientes cuando se aplica sobre un Entry junto con la definición de este.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías agregar el parametro que determina la variable donde se va a almacenar el dato ingresado.

variable.set(" ")

nombre = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = variable)

Print(nombre.get())